# Snippet execution for Java code on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Java 9 introduced the [jshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jshell) command line tool for [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) and its *[API - `jdk.jshell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/package-summary.html)*.

Using the APIs integrated with Stack Overflow, it seems pretty feasible to execute Java snippets as good as today we can see the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) answers/questions including relative snippets. Is this part of the roadmap or already implemented using some other approach?

Origin of thought => Answers from [a sample JavaScript tagged question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061160/merge-two-arrays-with-alternating-values#47061292).

Comment: Does that snippet then run in my browser or does it need a server?

Comment: @rene that might need a server (JVM instance) to execute on probably.

Comment: The javascript snippets run in your browser. That requires much less serverside setup and resources and complexity. Your FR might need 6 to 8 years before being implemented.

Comment: @rene you mean 6 to 8 *weeks*?

Comment: @StephenLeppik for those who still have hope, sure.

Comment: This would be an insane amount of server side setup and maintenance. There's a lot of other, arguably more important things that need SO devs' attention...

Comment: Topic seem to be brought up about weekly for different languages... always with the same suggestion "please run this buggy untrusted code on your servers as I promise everything will be good and code will not have buggy untrusted behavior". So far no positive feedback recorded for such suggestions.

Comment: How would this be useful? We don't need all Java answers to be self-contained, ready-to-execute "Hello world" snippets. In my opinion, Stack Snippets were a mistake, so this would *definitely* be taking it too far. Stack Overflow is not a tutoring service, and writing all sample code so it's ready to execute would just be *far* too noisy.

Comment: Stack Snippets were a mistake, @CodyGray? Did I miss some official statement on that? Where can I find it?

Comment: My opinion, @Will. Isn't that official enough?

Comment: Only when you have a paystub, @CodyGray :)

Answer (score 10):

Stack Snippets were added as an alternative to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) because:

- it's easy to implement
- it doesn't add much server load (it runs in-browser)
- JSFiddle links were already common, and already had to be accompanied by code
- it's nice to have the demo as part of the answer in case JSFiddle goes down

Now, let's look at your proposal:

- it has a few hurdles (the servers probably don't have Java installed)
- it would add server load (especially long/inefficient snippets)
- links to things like IDEone aren't very common

Comment: Never mind the security holes this opens up for running things server side (or effect on production - someone might manage to take over whole CPUs...).

Comment: @Oded:  Ephemeral Docker containers could alleviate the latter, but I respect the concerns overall.

Comment: How to run java snippet in StackOverflow? As we can run HTML, CSS, and Javascript in StackOverflow but don't know about java.